# Plot 2D principal compoents

Tags: matlab

New to Matlab.
Created script to generate 2D distribution and determine its principal components.

My method to plot the principal components is tortuous. There must be a more elegant way to plot the principal components.What is it?

And can I get arrows on the ends of my line segments? 
Here is my .m file:

```
%Distrubtion variances
xx = 2;
yy = .6;
xy = .5;

%Create distribution data
A = mvnrnd([0 0] , [xx xy; xy yy], 100);

%Get principal components of data
coeff = pca(A);

%Plot distribution
h = plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),'b.');
hold on

%Do crazy stuff to plot principal components
temp=zeros(2,4);
temp(:, 2:2:end) = coeff;
scalefactor=10; %Make the lines longer
temp=scalefactor * temp
X=temp(1:2:end);
Y=temp(2:2:end);
plot(X, Y, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);

%format plot
axis('square')
grid on;
xlabel('X Axis');
ylabel('Y Axis');
xlim([-10, 10]);
ylim([-10 10])

shg;
hold off;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be more reasonable. The `quiver` function plots arrows. ([See docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html)). You still need to size the arrows yourself though. Perhaps compute the range of your data instead of 10, and use that in both the scaling factor and the axes limits.

```
n = length(coeff);
coeff = 10 * coeff; % Make the lines longer
quiver(zeros(1,n), zeros(1, n), coeff(1,:), coeff(2,:), 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

Also, I don't know what version of MATLAB you are using, but `pca` is `princomp` in my version.